# Array manipulations in Ocaml

Tags: arrays, ocaml, combinatorics

I am trying to do all combinations of an Array in Ocaml.
I am trying to do a recursive function that recives an array and its initial state need to be `let a = [|0;0;0|]` and i need to change it recursivly like in the first iteration needs to be `a = [|1;0;0|]` and the next one `a = [|0;1;0|]` and so on until it reaches `a = [|1;1;1|]` making all the possible combinations, so in this case needs to do 2^3 changes. 
I know that im not been very explicit but its a bit hard to me to explain, but if someone could help me i would be grateful.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let combinaison f n =
  let rec aux acc n =  
    if n=0 then List.iter f acc
    else (
      aux (List.map (fun l -> 0::l  ) acc) (n-1);  
      aux (List.map (fun l -> 1::l  ) acc) (n-1);  
    )
  in
  aux [[]] n
;;
```

Test

```
combinaison ( fun lx -> 
  let a=Array.of_list lx in
  Array.iter ( fun x ->
    Printf.printf "%d " x
  ) a ;
  Printf.printf "\n"
) 3;;

0 0 0 
1 0 0 
0 1 0 
1 1 0 
0 0 1 
1 0 1 
0 1 1 
1 1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

An array is a mutable data structure, so if you're going to mutate it in every recursive call, then the mutation will be taken in place. Basically, it means, that after `2^3` calls, the state of array will be the last combination. So, there is no point in doing this at all. A valid solution would be to create a function, that will take an initial array, and will return a list of all combinations. An even more efficient solution is to write a function, that will take another function, and applies it to all combinations (or fold over all combinations). This will allow you to save memory, as you don't need to store all the combinations.

The outline would be to implement the following interface:

```
type state
val zero : state
val next : state -> state option
val value : state -> int array
```

Where state will be a cursor, that will move through the space of combinations. It can be an integer or an integer array, or anything else. Once these functions are implemented you can easily implement your function as follows:

```
let fold_combinations f init = 
  let rec fold state x = 
     let x = f (value state) x in
     match next state with
     | None -> x
     | Some state -> fold state x in
  fold zero init
```

Finally, your example shows not all possible combinations or permutations, but all possible binary values of bit width equal to the length of the input array. If this is really a task that you're trying to solve, then you can just translate an integer into a binary representation. In that case, the good choice for the `state` would be `int`, and then `next` function is an increment, that will stop at `2^k-1`, where `k` is the length of the initial state. And the `value` function will just translate an integer into the array of bits, where the `n`-th bit (element) can be determined as `state land (1 lsl n)`. You can use `Array.init` to create a fresh new array every time, alternatively, you can just iterate over the existing array. This will be more efficient, but error-prone.